# setting vim map in function in vim script

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to do a small plugin for vim to let me browse the clear case history of a file, but I am having trouble getting started. I need help with setting up the mapping exposed to the user.

Here is the bare minimum version of what I've done

```
function! s:DefineLeftKeyMaps()
    echom 'in defineLeft'
    nnoremap  <leader>k <Plug>MinimalDoSomething
endfunction


noremap <script> <Plug>MinimalDoSomething    <SID>DoSomething
noremap <SID>DoSomething :call <SID>DoSomething()<CR>

function! s:DoSomething()
    echom 'In DoSomething'
endfunction

command! InitCCTTSample call s:DefineLeftKeyMaps()
```

I need to set the final map exposed to the user in a function cause it will be used in a split where I open up different files (eventually using said mapping). Since it is a buffer local map i assume i need to reset it every time.

Edit:
The problem with the above solution was that even thou the mapping was it didn't do anything.

`:map` reported:

```
....
....
\k     * <Plug>MinimalDoSomething
....
....
```

The reason was that I used `noremap` instead of `map`, so the subsequent mapping to the function call was ignored

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`<plug>`-mappings are difficult to define as buffer local mappings. Indeed the end-user cannot define them in their `.vimrc`, and to define them in a ftplugin, that'll mean you'll need to associate a filetype to your split buffers.

You'll need to provide a hook to the end user. I see two solutions

1. Provide a function where the end user will be able to register her/his preferences in their `.vimrc`.

   ```
   " .vimrc
   call your#plug#tune_mappings({'<Plug>MinimalDoSomething': '<localleader>left'})
   ```
2. Expose a User Event for the user to do stuff (like defining the mappings) when you trigger the event from your plugin.

   ```
   " .vimrc
   augroup YourPlugUser
     au!
     au User TuneKeyBindings let b:maplocalleader = ',,'
     au User TuneKeyBindings nmap <buffer> <localleader><left> <Plug>MinimalDoSomething
   aug END

   " your plugin
   split yourplug://foobar
   doautocommand User TuneKeyBindings 
   if !hasmapto('<Plug>MinimalDoSomething, 'n')
     nmap <buffer> <leader>k <Plug>MinimalDoSomething
   endif
   ```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to answer me and would like to express my gratitude. Thank you!

My issue, however, was actually a lot simpler so ill provide the answer myself in case somebody else has the same problem

Comment: Indeed I missed that. BTW, I doubt you really want to define a global mapping as it should be restricted to the new split/scratch buffer.

Comment: Thanks again!   :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesnt work is because I used `nnoremap  <leader>k <Plug>MinimalDoSomething`  rather than `nmap  <leader>k <Plug>MinimalDoSomething`

Cheers